# Half-Reactions of Hydroxide

Tags: electrochemistry, redox

The following is the equation I have:

$$\ce{Ca(s) + 2H2O(l) -> Ca(OH)2 v  + H2 ^}$$

I am tasked to write the half-reaction equations for both the oxidation and/or reduction process. So, currently I have:
$$\ce{ Ca(s) -> Ca^{2+}(aq) + 2e-}\quad\text{(oxidation)}$$

but I'm not sure how do you write the reduction equation for the water and hydroxide.

Any help is appreciated :)

**P.S.:** I have no idea how to superscript or subscript in the forum.

Comment: Balance this for the reduction step: xH2O ---> H2 + y OH-

Comment: that would be: 2H2O --> H2+ 2OH-    Is that correct?

Comment: Right! since the oxidation is -2 electrons (Ca to Ca++) and the reduction (0 to -2) +2 electrons, just add the two reactions and simplify if needed.

Comment: Just so I'm getting this right: My Reduction equation reaction would be 2H2O --> H2 + 2OH-. Is there no e- required in this case?

Comment: Of course e- is required, otherwise there would be no reduction. Besides, your equation must be balanced in charge as strict as it must be balanced in all elements.

Comment: Grimlock: You may want to look at this link to balance redox equations in elements and electrons in base and acid: http://ursula.chem.yale.edu/~chem220/chem220js/STUDYAIDS/redox.htm

Comment: So, I've updated my answer to include the electron gained. Is this correct?

Answer (score 2):

Alright, so I've worked out my answer (thanks to [@user55119](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users/55119/user55119)). The Reduction step was:

> $$\ce{ 2H2O_{(l)} + 2e^- -> 2OH^-_{(aq)} + H_2_{(g)}}\quad\text{(Reduction)}$$